# Kafka Consumer is not safe for multi-threaded access Exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

when i am creating consumer with kafka i am getting following exception:

exception:

> Kafka Consumer is not safe for multi-threaded access Exception

*More than 100 consumer subscribing topic at same time and getting records also same time.*

i added following code

```
//KafkaConsumer Configuration 

KafkaConsumer<String, Object> kafkaConsumer;
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVER_URL + ":" + KAFKA_SERVER_PORT);
properties.put("group.id", GROUP_ID);
properties.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
properties.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
properties.put("key.deserializer", JsonDeserializer.class);
properties.put("value.deserializer", JsonDeserializer.class);
kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);


//Subscribe Consumer

kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("Topic_Name"));

//Get Records From Beginning

while (true) {
    kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(kafkaConsumer.assignment());
    ConsumerRecords<String, Object> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, Object> record : records) {
        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), 
            record.key(), record.value());
    }
}

//Get Records Using WebSocket this section continuously

ConsumerRecords<String, Object> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
for (ConsumerRecord<String, Object> record : records) {
    System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), 
        record.key(), record.value());
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178668/discussion-on-question-by-kailas-biradar-kafka-consumer-is-not-safe-for-multi-th).

Comment: @BhargavRao Thank u for suggest

Comment: @cricket_007 Poll interval 1s use then not get records. After 4-5 attempts they give the records

Comment: @cricket_007 i don't know how to implement kafkaStreams, if you know please help.

Comment: Now i'm use kafka stream thank u @cricket_007 for suggest.

Comment: @cricket_007 can i use seperate consumer microservice application solve this issue.

Comment: I don't see why not

Comment: ok. thank u @cricket_007

Comment: @cricket_007 can i got the which consumer get the records from topic.?

Comment: Not very easily, no. Other than offsets, that's not something that the brokers will track. You would need the consumer to send a message to an external system to say it has received a particular message content.

Comment: @cricket_007 ok

Comment: @cricket_007 In kafka config server.properties can i set listeners and advertised.listeners same ip...?

Comment: @cricket_007 i have error topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE, i'm not understand why this occur

Comment: Please post a new question, not continue issues in the comments.

Comment: @cricket_007 ok